# Why is preservation of affine structure an assumption for mixed states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, quantum-states

I'm reading Isham's *Lecture on Quantum Theory*, and towards the end of Chapter 6, in Section 6.4.4, *The Time Development of a Mixed State*, he shows (*not defines*) that $\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}:=|\psi_t\rangle\langle\psi_t|$ evolves as $$\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}=\hat{U}(t, t_1)\hat{P}_{|\psi_{t_1}\rangle}\hat{U}(t_1, t),\tag{1}$$ where $t_1$ is some fixed instant in time and $\hat{U}(t_2,t_1):=e^{-{i\over\hbar}\hat{H}(t_2-t_1)}$, where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian.

Now, a mixed state is a convex sum $\hat{\rho}(t):=\sum_{d=1}^D w_d \hat{P}_{|\psi_{d,t}\rangle}$. Isham states that it "if we assume that the time evolution preserves this affine structure (and this *is* an assumption), the evolution of a general density matrix $\hat{\rho}$ will be described by Eq. (6.56) [which is equation $(1)$ with $\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}$ replaced with $\hat{\rho}(t)$]."

**Question:** But equation $(1)$ is clearly *linear* in $\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}$. *So doesn't preservation of affine structure automatically follow?*

---

By linear, I mean the following.

For any two states $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_t\rangle$, $\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}=\hat{U}(t, t_1)\hat{P}_{|\psi_{t_1}\rangle}\hat{U}(t_1, t)$ and $\hat{P}_{|\phi_t\rangle}=\hat{U}(t, t_1)\hat{P}_{|\phi_{t_1}\rangle}\hat{U}(t_1, t)$ *imply* that $\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle} + \hat{P}_{|\phi_t\rangle}=\hat{U}(t, t_1)\bigl(\hat{P}_{|\psi_{t_1}\rangle}+\hat{P}_{|\phi_{t_1}\rangle}\bigr)\hat{U}(t_1, t)$. Also, for any scalar $\lambda$, it follows that $\lambda\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}=\hat{U}(t, t_1)\bigl(\lambda\hat{P}_{|\psi_{t_1}\rangle}\bigr)\hat{U}(t_1, t)$.

Comment: (1) is just some abstract rule that maps matrices (representing pure states) to other matrices (also representing pure states). A priori it says nothing about mixed states at all. Your argument is saying that if you _extend_ (1) so that it also applies to mixed states, and assume that this extension is linear, then you get the quoted result. That's just in agreement with what Isham says.

Comment: @knzhou It doesn't need to be defined, IMO, since $\hat{\rho}$ is just an affine sum of $\hat{P}_{|\psi\rangle}$'s.

Comment: @knzhou I agree that it doesn’t *a priori* say anything about mixed states. But can’t we *conclude* what I claim just by mathematical reasoning?

Comment: Suppose that I was $4$ feet tall at the age of $12$ and $5$ feet tall at the age of $15$ and grew linearly in between. Therefore, we have established mathematically that height is linear in time. But can't we _conclude_ that I will be $100$ feet tall at the age of $300$ by mathematical reasoning? No, for the same reason as you can't here. It would be a natural extrapolation of what we already know, but by virtue of being an extrapolation it makes additional assumptions.

Comment: @knzhou Age is *not* a linear function throughout one’s life (you say that it is linear in between the age of 12 and 15 and not necessarily at other times). On the other hand, equation (1) *is* linear for *all* $\hat{P}_{|\psi\rangle}$’s.

Comment: This is what I think is meant by the "assumption". Equation $(1)$ is clearly linear in $\hat{P}_{|\psi_t\rangle}$ in the sense you describe. But, the non-trivial claim is that the density matrix preserves the affine structure as a convex sum. In particular, $\rho(t)=\sum_d w_d|\psi_d(t)\rangle\langle\psi_d(t)|$ is the non-trivial physical assumption. Mathematically, you could also add a little $t$ subscript to $w_d$ and then the linearity of equation $(1)$ won't help you get Isham's equation $(6.56)$.

Comment: @DvijD.C. But without the little sub $t$, would it not be derivable?